# Problema al utilizar expresiones regulares en python

Tags: python

Espero me puedan ayudar con este problema.

Estoy utilizando expresiones regulares en python, la expresión funciona bien si toma la cadena de texo declarada directo del programa pero si utilizo un archivo txt, la expresión regular ya no hace match.

import re

## Abrir el archivo de configuración

with open('C:\Users\hhmaldon\Documents\Python\Python xr\interfaces.txt','r') as file:
config = file.read()

match_pattern = re.findall(r'^(Gi\w+\S+\s+\S+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)', config)

print(match_pattern)

Gracias por su apoyo!

Comment: Hola Joe, para poder ayudarte, deberías mostrarnos el contenido del ***txt***, y que salida esperas.

Comment: Deberías mostrar el contenido del archivo y explicar el propósito de la expresión regular. Sin ambas cosas no se puede evaluar el código.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que se deba a que en el archivo de texto tienes saltos de línea, retornos de carro etc que no estas considerando en tu expresión regular,  prueba reemplazando esos meta caracteres con strip() y replace() para despues si evaluar la cadena con re.findall():

```
with open('C:\Users\botarguin\Documents\Python\Python xr\interfaces.txt', 'r') as file:
    config = file.read().strip().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')

texto = 'GigabitEthernet0/0/1/0.13 201.96.19.6 Up Up default'

match_pattern = re.findall(r'^(Gi\w+\S+\s+\S+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)', texto)

print(match_pattern)
```

otra alternativa seria modificar la propia expresion.

Comment: este es un fragmento del txt interface                      IP-Address      Status                
GigabitEthernet0/1/0/0         unassigned      Shutdown              Down    
GigabitEthernet0/1/0/4         unassigned      Shutdown              Down    
GigabitEthernet0/1/0/5         unassigned      Shutdown              Down    
y yo quiero extraer las Giga  con las 3 siguientes strings, ya le quite los espacios pero sigue sin guardarlos, si lo tomo directo del programa si lo hace pero si lo extraigo del txt no.

Comment: Hola gracias ya lo solucione al eliminar los espacios del txt. gracias por su ayuda